# Read Environmental Variables Each Call or Store in Static Variables?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

My azure function is reading in information from the configuration. These variable's won't change past initial startup. Would it be better to poll the environment every time they are called, or to save them in a static variable. ex:

```
public static class FooBar{
   [FunctionName("FooBar")]
   public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
   {
      var bar = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("bar");
      ...
```

or

```
public static class FooBar{
   static string foo = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("foo");
   [FunctionName("FooBar")]
   public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
   {
      ...
```

Comment: Environment variables are brought into the configuration system by default so you can grab them out of configuration, you don't need to use GetEnvironmentVariable.

Comment: check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#working-with-options-and-settings

Comment: No need to poll, function app need to restart to update the environment variable, so static variable before go to the logic of function is a better way. It just run only once.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be better to poll the environment every time they are called,
> or to save them in a static variable.

I suggest you to save them in a static variable before go to the logic of function if you need it. Poll the environment variable in the logic of function is meaningless, this is because the environment settings need to restart the function app host on azure(On local you need to restart the tools that you use to run the function app.). So , of course it is better to call it only once, because you do not need to poll.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection with the Configuration Extensions is the way to go here. It reads the config at app startup, and the configuration object can be passed to the functions.

When you change a setting it restarts the app, so DI processing would get the new configuration.

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class MyFunction
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public MyFunction(IConfiguration config, ILogger<MyFunction> logger)
    {
        _config = config;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer)
    {
        var item = _config["SomeOption"];
    }

}
```